# Compare dates in SQL || use dates in where clause

Tags: mysql, sql, database

**In the date column of table in sql what query should is use to get the details of table having dates after year of 2015**

[image: This is the table]

*what query should i use to retrieve all details having orderdate after year of 2015*

Comment: None of your sample data is after 2015, so no rows would be returned.

Comment: What is the datatype of column `orderdate`?

Comment: the datatype of orderdate is date

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would use a date comparison:

```
where orderdate >= '2016-01-01'
```